# Best Data structure to perform Kruskal's algorithm on a sparce graph?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

If there is no constraint on space, what would be the best data structure to choose to preform kruskals algorithm given that the graph will be sparce.

I'm thinking of using a Singly linked list implementation

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a student from ECE 250 at the University of Waterloo.  Unfortunately, the project deadline is now over.

Comment: This is hardly an answer to a question.

Comment: This is hardly a question.

Comment: Aha yes I was a student in your class sir. I ended up using a mutiway set from the standard template library. Just wondering, would a BST have been a better solution to store the weights?

Comment: @nana he's doing his job as a professor to make sure his students don't cheat on projects and assignments, nothing wrong with that

Answer (score 1):

Yes. :-)  Unfortunately for this student, the question is poorly posed as it does not give details about other operations relevant to the problem at hand.  Had the graph already existed, a heap of sorta would be appropriate; however, the construction of the graph was part of the problem so it was more optimal to store the edges in a linear order based on weight.  The makes Kruskal's algorithm much faster.

Comment: THE PROGRAMMING GOD @DouglasWHarder HIMSELF HAS ENTERED STACKOVERFLOW